# jQuery Offset reading fixed navigation instead of actual divs in nested structure

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with the jQuery `offset()` function. Please take a look at the jsfiddle file for the code and preview.

Quick overview: I am making a one page website that contains multiple pages. Each page is inside a div. Now in the navigation bar, on the top, there are anchors that once clicked, takes you towards the div that is associated with the anchor. Once an anchor is clicked, it becomes active and I used css to customize that active anchor, to make it stand out from the non active. This is the same as focus. However, one problem I am having is when the user scrolls, he passes different div's. Take a look at this snippet

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.section').each(function() {
        //  alert($(this).offset());
        //  alert($(this).offset().top());
        //  alert($(this).offset().bottom());
        //  alert($(window).scrollTop());

    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top()) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('nav a').removeClass('active');
            $('nav a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

This function compares the `$(this).offset()` to the window. However, the problem is that the navigation bar is always floating on the top of the screen regardless of where you scroll. And `$(this).offset().top()` is always returning the navigation bar (since its at the top). So this has no affect to the div's that are below.

I have included a sample on jsfiddle for you to get a live preview of what my problem is.

https://jsfiddle.net/exxvq48m/11/

Any advice? thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

You are trying to use `top` as a function. That is causing the problem 1.
Then second issue is `$('nav a[href=#'+ id +']')`. Here you need to enclose href value in quotes. So you code should be:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.section').each(function() {
        //  alert($(this).offset());
        //  alert($(this).offset().top());
        //  alert($(this).offset().bottom());
        //  alert($(window).scrollTop());

      if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) { // <<< changed
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('nav a').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a[href="#'+ id +'"]').addClass('active'); // <<< changed
      }
    });
});
```

That should work for you.